# Prepostition 'as to' in poetry

Tags: prepositions, adverbs, prepositional-phrases, poetry, archaicisms

So I ran accross this line in a poem of Alexander Pope:

> Vice is a monster of so frightful mien As to be hated needs but to be
> seen; Yet seen too oft, familiar with her face, We first endure, then
> pity, then embrace.

Dryden has it as well:

> For truth has such a face and such a mien As to be loved needs only to
> be seen.

I do not understand what the "As to be (participle) needs to be (participle)." Construction shall mean. I figure "needs" is an archaic adverb meaning "necessarily". It still does not make sense to me. Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: *For truth has such a face and such a mien **that it needs only to be seen to be loved.*** Or even more "naturally" for non-poetic contexts today: *For truth has a face and a mien **such that it needs only to be seen to be loved.***

Comment: English has changed since Pope and Dryden, so it's not surprising you do not understand it. Plus, it's poetry, and old poetry at that, in a style now unknown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pope: Vice is a monster.
The monster is so frightening that all that is required for it to be hated is for it to be seen.
Seen too often, however, and we become familiarised with the monster's face.
We first put up with it.
We then pity it.
And finally, we embrace it (vice).

Dryden: You only need to see truth to love it, as truth has the kind of face and expression that make you fall in love with it as soon as you see it.

'[so as to](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=so%20as%20to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cso%20as%20to%3B%2Cc0)' is an expression equivalent to 'in order to' which was used more frequently in the late 19th Century. Its use has declined since, but it's still current, although the examples you've given are more complex because of the poetic choices made.

Comment: Golly me! Thank you very much indeed Leon. It did not cross my mind at all that there is an ellipsis of the "so". Suddenly the line unraveled entirely. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

"The appearance of vice is so frightful that you need only see it to immediately hate it." *Needs* is not the adverb here, just the ordinary verb.

The construction is the same as *It is so small as to be often disregarded* - so small *that it is* disregarded.